# doing 1-d convolution in batches/parallel

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, convolution

I am having following code, basically doing 1-d convolution on each row of a 2-D matrix. The convolution kernel is the same. So really the SIMD case.

```
a = [   1,2,3,4,5;
        6,7,8,9,7; 
        7,6,2,3,4; 
        23, 54, 1, 3 ,7];

f = [1,2,3];


for n = 1:size(a,1)
    conv(a(n,:),f,'same')
end
```

When the matrix size(and the kernel size) gets larger, the speed really becomes a problem. I am wondering is there any way to this in batch (parallelize this process)?

I did something like this, but the results are different from above code:

```
a = [   1,2,3,4,5;
        6,7,8,9,7; 
        7,6,2,3,4; 
        23, 54, 1, 3 ,7];

f = [1,2,3];

ff = repmat(f, [size(a,1) 1]);

for n = 1:size(a,1)
    conv(a(n,:),f,'same')
end

convn(a,ff,'same')

conv2(f,2,a,'same')
```

Please advise. Thanks.

**PS: 
I am currently only seeking solution using convolution, not using fft equivalent.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use a 2-dimensional convolution:

```
conv2(1, f, a, 'same')
```

or

```
conv2(a, f, 'same')
```

In the first method, the first argument is `1` because it's a column-wise convolution, and based on what you said, you only want to do row convolution, which is taken care of using the second argument, `f`.

From the Matlab docs for `conv2`:

> C = conv2(H1, H2, A) first convolves each column of A with the vector
>       H1 and then convolves each row of the result with the vector H2.

Convolving a scalar `1` along the columns is an identity operation, allowing the `f` vector to convolve along the original matrix rows, which is the desired result.

For the second method above, this is a direct 2-dimensional convolution of the two input matrices, so if you take care to understand your input dimensions and argument order, this actually performs a faster operation.

Comment: It works as it should. Thanks. I am curious, so to do convolution along row direction, the first parameter then should be 2, and my f should be a column vector?

Comment: This would be more efficient if you transposed `a` and convolved along columns: `conv2(f,1,a.','same')`. -- at least for larger `f`.

Comment: @Nick: read the documentation to `conv2`. `1` is not the direction, it's the filter for the columns.

Comment: Why not just `conv2(a, f, 'same')`?

Comment: @LuisMendo yes, that is true; I updated the answer with a note that this is actually the more efficient method

Comment: Great! Thank you guys all for the clarification. I always thought conv2() is only for 2-D convolution. Thanks!